Change source IP address, send over eth0 instead of lo
If a packet is sent using TCP and source address 127.1.1.1 (lo) and destination port 80, I want to be sent over eth0 and source address a.b.c.d instead.
How can I get this working?
I tried:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 127.1.1.1 -j SNAT --to-source a.b.c.d

However this is still getting a timeout:
nc -s 127.1.1.1 <external IP> 80

Thanks a lot.

Why don't just use the address of eth0 instead? In this form the question doesn't look like a reasonable practice. And it only makes sense as an XY problem. What you are trying to achieve this way?

I am wondering a bit about what you want to achieve.
If it is just port 80 on a single ip address you need access to, then port forwarding is by far the easiest way to go.
However the selected ip address in your question suggest you want to utilize multiple ip addresses on the localnet subnet (127.0.0.0/8).
In that case I think you are looking into implementing a 1:1 NAT.
This require an available subnet like 10.1.0.0/16 and then use source and destination routing so any ip package from 127.1.x.x appear to originate from 10.1.x.x.
Similar you want all ip packages bound for 10.1.x.x be forwarded to 127.1.x.x.
In a nutshell:

10.1.1.1 maps to 127.1.1.1.
10.1.1.2 maps to 127.1.1.2.
etc.

I asked a similar question back in 2021 and I believe it can be used on this question too.
That would mean you need to use the following commands:
# Translates any ip address from 127.1.x.x into 10.1.x.x
# Note the '-s' after POSTROUTING

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 127.1.1.0/16 -j NETMAP --to 10.1.0.0/16

# Translates any traffic for 10.1.x.x into 127.1.x.x
# Note the '-d' after PREROUTING

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.1.0.0/16 -j NETMAP --to 127.1.0.0/16

This would also mean you need a static route to your router telling that the subnet 10.1.0.0/16 is reachable through the IP address of your server.
Like for instance the command:
ip route add 10.1.0.0/16 via A.B.C.D, where A.B.C.D the ip address you use to communicate with the server.
Does this answer fit your requirements?

I still get connection time out if I use nc as described above. On outgoing connections with source IP 127.1.1.1 and dest port 80, I want to replace the source IP by a.b.c.d (and use eth0 instead of lo). Thanks for your help.

Well what happens in theory with rules described in my post is that anyone can contact the webserver by writing 10.1.1.1 in their browser. Since the clients do not belong to the 10.1.0.0/16 subnet the will then forward the request to the router, which has a static route for 10.1.0.0/16 that is pointing towards your host A.B.C.D. When your host see that the request is for 10.1.1.1 it will then NAT translate it into 127.1.1.1 and thereby be seen by your webserver.


still getting a timeout

I assume that you have already set the net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet sysctl to 1, which is necessary for what you are doing. Otherwise nc should either just failed right away quietly or give you an Invalid argument error, depending on the variant of netcat you are using.
Although I'm not exactly sure what you mean by timeout when you are not using -w. Maybe you are referring to the fact that it stalls forever? In that case, AFAIK it more or less indicates that the destination host (or a router in between) has a firewall that dropped the packet. (Without such a firewall, normally the OS would just reset the connection right away when it is TCP, although GNU netcat somehow seems to be a bit slow on "accepting the fact", while OpenBSD netcat just exits right away.)
The thing is, the packet may not have taken the link you want it to (e.g., the eth0 one).
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 127.1.1.1 -j SNAT --to-source a.b.c.d

The rule is fine, as in, if there's only one link that could ever be the one you want the traffic to take, and all the possible destination addresses are covered by a route of that link, it is fine.
The problem is:

If ... I want to be sent over eth0

It sounds like there are multiple links, and you for some reason want the source address you picked to be what determines which link certain traffics would take. (And for some peculiar reason, you decided to make use of the loopback address block for the task.)
Yet SNAT does not affect routing, as it is applied after the routing decision has been made (note POSTROUTING).
Usually routing works like this: a route in the main route table with the longest prefix length that covers the destination address would be used; if there are more than one route (with the same longest prefix length), the one with lower metric would be used. (I don't know what would happen if their metric are also the same; personally I just consider that it would result in nondeterministic behavior and something to be avoided.)
As you can see, other than factors in the routing mechanism itself, the destination address is the only thing that matters.
If you need it to take the source address into consideration, you need policy-based routing, a.k.a. ip rule + alternate route table.
For example:
ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 table 111
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 table 111
ip rule add iif lo from 127.1.1.1 lookup 111

Note that iif lo in the rule does not have anything to do with the fact that you somehow want to leverage the loopback address block. It just "tighten" the rule so that it would only be applied to traffics originated from the host itself (i.e., in case this host is working as a router for some other host).
Also note that the from match should have the "original" source address, not the "target" source address set by SNAT.
There are some more "selectors" you can use to further "tighten" the rule, such as ipproto tcp dport 80.
P.S. Writing this answer does not mean that I think what you are trying to do (as in, your approach) makes sense. It's just that I am not interested in finding out whether it is an XYProblem, at least not until / unless you actively present all the context behind your idea.

Think of POSTROUTING as what to do on the way back (the reverse process). You need that too. But what you are looking for is PREROUTING. That’s used to define what happens with packets before they are sent or where to forward them. The real kicker is that if the traffic originates on localhost, NAT PREROUTING will not actually take effect. In this case you want to just use OUTPUT table to -j DNAT to forward outgoing packets to another IP. DNAT will also masquerade the source IP as you want. If traffic comes from outside that you want to DNAT then add it to NAT PREROUTING instead (iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING … -j DNAT —-to …). The IUTOUT table is in the default filter chain so just: iptables -I OUTPUT … -j DNAT —-to …). You will want the POSTROUTING or INPUT rule in the opposite direction though as you need to reverse the NAT of the IP (rewriting the source/dest IP). That’s what SNAT is for here (source nat) - for packets coming back.

Sorry, I forgot to add: destination port is always 80. So: on outgoing connections with source IP 127.1.1.1 and dest port 80, I want to replace the source IP by a.b.c.d (and use eth0 instead of lo). Thanks for your help.

Which interface the packets come out of will be dictated by routing rules (see: ip route ls). With iptables you just choose destination IP. Something along these lines (on vacation in hotel right now, so cannot test): iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp —dport 80 —destination 127.1.1.1 -j DNAT —to a.b.c.d:80. You’ll want a masquerade or SNAT rule in POSTROUTING with the reverse of these to route responses back to 127.1.1.1
